# Update mysql query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It looks really simple but I can't make it work for some reason.
This is the query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `alliance` 
             SET limit=limit+5, bank=bank-".$price."
             WHERE ID='".$ad['ID']."'");
```

This is the error printed:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit=limit+5, bank=bank-10000 WHERE ID='4'' at line 1`

I tried this ways as well:

`mysql_query("UPDATE alliance SET limit=limit+'5', bank=bank-'".$price."' WHERE ID='".$ad['ID']."'");`

`mysql_query("UPDATE alliance SET limit=limit+5, bank=bank-".$price." WHERE ID=".$ad['ID']);`

Can someone please help me? It the first time I stuck with small query like that.

Comment: Since LIMIT is a reserved keyword I suggest you update your table and use a different word.  It will make your code read a bit cleaner.  You can use UPPERLIMIT or maybe COUNT...whatever word you think is relevant.

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if you're not careful to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) every value you put in your query, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices.

Comment: Thx, I'll read about PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). So if you're going to use it you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `alliance` 
         SET `limit`=`limit`+5, bank=bank-".$price."
         WHERE ID='".$ad['ID']."'");
```

Comment: Wow, didn't cross my mind! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yet you put `alliance` in backticks even though it didn't need it.